# Excel displaying infinitely repeated value in cell

Tags: excel, formatting, vba

My Excel spreadsheet contains a column whose rows can contain the value `0`, `1` or `2`. My VBA code sums the number of `0`s (specifically, values that aren't `1` or `2`) and puts the count into the cell below. This seems to run fine, as the value of the cell at the end is equal to the number of `0`s as it should, however the numbers are displayed like this (should be just `9`):

[image: Infinite Numbers]

The numbers repeat infinitely.

My VBA code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("F22")) Is Nothing And Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F21")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim count As Integer
        For i = 4 To 21:
            If Not Cells(i, "F").Value = 1 And Not Cells(i, "F").Value = 2 Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next i
        Cells(22, "F").Value = count
    End If
End Sub
```

Is this a VBA problem or is my document incorrectly formatted?

Comment: Is one of your keys stuck on your keyboard?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent The value is 9 as it should be. Whereas it displays 99999....

Comment: It should be very easy to eliminate VBA as the issue, if you know how to trouble shoot VBA.  That leaves corruption, OR a format issue (not that I can imagine it, but take steps to rule it out), or the @peege effect.

Comment: I would write      if Cells(i, "F").value < 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have formatted the cell with Horizontal: alignment `Fill`.

Comment: Great call! Thanks this solved the issue, I mistakenly had it on fill.